# How to set a variable's value to shortcut.arguments using vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to set a variable's value to shortcut.argument using VBS. But it doesn't work. Please tell me the solution.

This is my code:

```
Set WShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set lnk = WShell.CreateShortcut("test.lnk")
lnk.Arguments = WScript.Arguments(0)
lnk.Save
```

row 3 doesnt work...

Comment: Show us your code and explain more your request !

Comment: Ive edited my question just now :)

Comment: If the error is "Subscript out of range" make sure you pass at least one argument to your script.

Comment: thank you. I pass one argument to my script like this:

Comment: ' "test.vbs" "aaa" ' in cmd

Comment: So what **is** the error/unexpected behavior?

Comment: it works pretend nothing is wrong. but doesnt set a argument. lnk.Arguments = "aaa" works.

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
lnk.Arguments = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
```

Comment: @user6191333 - what is the error.E.g. the line `WScript.Echo ( WScript.Arguments.Item(0) )` works without problems.Have you passed any arguments to the script.

Comment: WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Item(0) works well, "aaa" is displayed.

Comment: @user6191333 Where do you try to save the shortcut? If it is in program files or in the windows folder you might need admin permissions.